# Unable to open any file from browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, filesaver.js

i'm using file-saver package to download files. The downloading is not the issue it seems to be the opening of any file. I console.log file from the files function logic below and get this:

```
File {name: '5ece9322f34d050a92546892.jpeg', lastModified: 1641918175691, lastModifiedDate: Tue Jan 11 2022 16:22:55 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 156, …}
    lastModified: 1641918175691
    lastModifiedDate: Tue Jan 11 2022 16:22:55 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    name: "5ece9322f34d050a92546892.jpeg"
    size: 156
    type: ".jpeg"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
    [[Prototype]]: File
```

I get the following error:

The file 5ece9322f34d050a92546892.jpeg could not be opened.It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise.

My code:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

  const files = ({url, fileName}) => {
    const extension = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('.'));
      const handleDownloadDocument = (fileUrl, name, ex) => {
        const file = new File([fileUrl], name, { type: ex });
        return saveAs(file);
      };

   return(<div onClick={() => handleDownloadDocument(url, fileName, extension)}> download </div>);

};
```

Comment: extension is not correct, for a url like this `sdsd.sd/sdsdsd.pdf`,  the extension would be `.pdf` which is not a valid mime type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

Comment: Where you getting sdsd.sd/sdsdsf.pdf from?

Comment: it is an example.